# Why zero after ajax call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I am learning Ajax first time with WordPress. I am implementing Ajax functionality with widget but I am getting 0 after form is submit.

Can you guide me and explain why this is happening so i can understand better.

My Code:

```
wp_enqueue_script('jquery');

/**
 * Add function to widgets_init that'll load our widget.
 * @since 0.1
 */
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'example_load_widgets' );

/**
 * Register our widget.
 * 'Example_Widget' is the widget class used below.
 *
 * @since 0.1
 */
function example_load_widgets() {
    register_widget( 'Example_Widget' );
}

/**
 * Example Widget class.
 * This class handles everything that needs to be handled with the widget:
 * the settings, form, display, and update.  Nice!
 *
 * @since 0.1
 */
class Example_Widget extends WP_Widget {

    /**
     * Widget setup.
     */
    function Example_Widget() {
        /* Widget settings. */
        $widget_ops = array( 'classname' => 'example', 'description' => __('An example widget that displays a person\'s name and sex.', 'example') );

        /* Widget control settings. */
        $control_ops = array( 'width' => 300, 'height' => 350, 'id_base' => 'example-widget' );

        /* Create the widget. */
        $this->WP_Widget( 'example-widget', __('Example Widget', 'example'), $widget_ops, $control_ops );
    }

    /**
     * How to display the widget on the screen.
     */
    function widget() {
            echo $name = $_POST['name'];
            ?>
            <form type="post" action="" id="newCustomerForm">

                <label for="name">Name:</label>
                <input name="name" type="text" />

                <input type="hidden" name="action" value="example_load_widgets"/>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
            </form>
            <br/><br/>
            <div id="feedback"></div>
            <br/><br/>

            <script type="text/javascript">
                jQuery('#newCustomerForm').submit(ajaxSubmit);

                function ajaxSubmit(){

                    var newCustomerForm = jQuery(this).serialize();

                    jQuery.ajax({
                        type:"POST",
                        url: "http://localhost/testing/wordpress/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
                        data: newCustomerForm,
                        success:function(data){
                            jQuery("#feedback").html(data);
                        },
                        error: function(errorThrown){
                            alert(errorThrown);
                        }  
                    });

                    return false;
                }
            </script>

            <?php
            die();
            add_action('wp_ajax_example_load_widgets', 'example_load_widgets');
            add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_example_load_widgets', 'example_load_widgets');

        }
    }
```

Comment: There are *many* things wrong with your code, I'd suggest starting again. If you search my answers here and at [wordpress.se], you'll find many working examples of Ajax for WP. Then, you'll have to integrate one of them with a working widget code. Oh, yes, you should be doing a plugin to implement this.

Comment: Thanks for your replay and guide me. I have refereed this tutorial for ajax and I tried with widget. `http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/tutorial-ajax-wordpress`

Comment: I suggest you come up with some working code. If no Answer is given, I think it's alright if you change the Question completely. If you do it, ping me and I'll take a look and retract the close vote.

Comment: Like brasofilo said - there are many things wrong there - but as a quick note : as of recent wordpress the ajax url should always be available as `ajaxurl` .. also, can you please see console log and errors to share ?

Comment: Belongs on http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have created ajax example like yours, may be it will help you.

Try this:

First create plugin and add this code:

```
<?php
    function sampleHelloWorld() {
    ?>
        <form type="post" action="" id="newCustomerForm">
            <label for="name">Name:</label>
            <input name="name" type="text" /><br /><br />

            <input type="hidden" name="action" value="addCustomer"/>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>

        <br/><br/>
        <div id="feedback"></div>
        <br/><br/>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery('#newCustomerForm').submit(ajaxSubmit);

            function ajaxSubmit(){

                var newCustomerForm = jQuery(this).serialize();

                jQuery.ajax({
                    type:"POST",
                    url: "http://localhost/testing/wordpress/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
                    data: newCustomerForm,
                    success:function(data){
                        jQuery("#feedback").html(data);
                    },
                    error: function(errorThrown){
                        alert(errorThrown);
                    }  
                });

                return false;
            }
        </script>
        <?php
    }

function widget_myHelloWorld($args) {
  extract($args);
  echo $before_widget;
  echo $before_title;?>Hello World Ajax<?php echo $after_title;
  sampleHelloWorld();
  echo $after_widget;
}

function myHelloWorld_init(){
  register_sidebar_widget(__('Hello World'), 'widget_myHelloWorld');     
}
add_action("plugins_loaded", "myHelloWorld_init");

wp_enqueue_script('jquery');

function addCustomer(){
    echo $name = $_POST['name'];
    die(); 
}

add_action('wp_ajax_addCustomer', 'addCustomer');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_addCustomer', 'addCustomer');
?>
```

Comment: What was causing the problem? What did you change?